# Issue with Inserting JSON data into MySQL database using Python, error in your SQL syntax

Tags: python, mysql, json

I am trying to insert some JSON data into a MySQL database using a python script.  Seems like it is close to working, but I keep getting an error that says:

```
python_mpps_1         | Error Code: 1064
python_mpps_1         | SQLSTATE 42000
python_mpps_1         | Message You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-create (dataset_in, mwl, dataset_out) VALUES ('{\"00000000\": {\"Value\": [2], ' at line 1
```

That is output by the try / catch in the script:

```
    try:
        mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO n-create (dataset_in, mwl, dataset_out) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (dataset_in, mwl , dataset_out))
        mydb.commit()
        print("Inserting N_CREATE" + str(mycursor.rowcount))
        mycursor.close()
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print(err)
        print("Error Code:", err.errno)
        print("SQLSTATE", err.sqlstate)
        print("Message", err.msg)
```

I put some debugging stuff in the script:

```
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="mysql_db", port = 3306, user="",password="",database="")
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    print(type(dataset_in))
    print(dataset_in)
    print(type(dataset_out))
    print(dataset_out)
    mwl = json.dumps(mwl[0])
    print(type(mwl))
    print(mwl)
```

and it prints out <class 'str'> as the datatype for all of the values that I want to insert, and they all validate as JSON using jsonlint.

I have a lot more details, and I've played around with changing the tables in the database from JSON to VARCHAR, etc and that does not help.  Also played around with using json.dump(var), etc., so it seems like it must just be s syntax issue with:

```
mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO n-create (dataset_in, mwl, dataset_out) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (dataset_in, mwl , dataset_out))
```

statement, which is what the 1064 means really.  Probably something simple, I hope, otherwise I can provide more details.

As an example, a snippet of dataset_out is as follows.  That is what it shows in the terminal via Docker when I print(dataset_out), but turncated it a bit.

```
{
    "00000000": {
        "Value": [2],
        "vr": "UL"
    },
    "00000002": {
        "Value": ["1.2.840.10008.3.1.2.3.3"],
        "vr": "UI"
    },
    "00000100": {
        "Value": [33088],
        "vr": "US"
    },
    "00000120": {
        "Value": [8],
        "vr": "US"
    },
    "00000800": {
        "Value": [0],
        "vr": "US"
    },
    "00000900": {
        "Value": [0],
        "vr": "US"
    }
}
```

Comment: "n-create" is not a valid table name.  Did you mean "n_create"?

Comment: I do.  That might be it.  Was about to hit the hay.  It is usually something simple !

Comment: That is it.  If you want to post the answer, go ahead.  BTW, what is the advantage to using JSON for JSON data ?  Can you actually to a search on property values that way, or should you add another column for things that you might actually want to search on or index.  JSON seems like a much more efficient way to deal with large JSON datasets.

Comment: @Tim Roberts You interested in working on a Python - Docker project, open source ?

Comment: Your JSON question doesn't make sense.  JSON is a great way for sending information between different apps, because it is language independent.  If you're using an SQL database, then I don't know why you would use JSON.  Store the data in relational form so you can do searches.  MongoDB uses JSON records as its native format, but it has sophisticated built-in query functions.

Comment: Actually, I would add a couple of other columns to index on, as a single value.  It is mostly to provide an audit trail so that I can look at the whole dataset if necessary.  I might actually  into MongoDB since I've never used it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"n-create" is not a valid table name. I suspect you meant "n_create".

Comment: or rather  `INSERT INTO \`n-create\` ...`